typescript fails to infer type from union of functions
what am I missing here?
type HandlerA = (firstArg: string) => number;
type HandlerB = (firstArg: string, secondArg: number) => string;

type Handler = HandlerA | HandlerB

// works
const testA: Handler = (a, b) => 'text'

// fails, bc a is implicitly of type 'any'
const testB: Handler = (a) => 10

As you can see, testB fails to infer HandlerA. Is there a way to solve this without beeing explicit like const testC: Handler = (a: string) => 10

No, you need to provide an explicit type somewhere; the issue you're hitting is described at ms/TS#10048 and apparently they don't want to fix it.

(see prev comment) Does that fully address the question? if so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

When using a union of function types, TypeScript can't infer the type if the provided function doesn't match all signatures. In the case of testB, it fails because HandlerB expects two arguments, but only one is provided, which causes the error. See issue pointed by @jcalz
Are you trying to overload your function?
function handler(firstArg: string): string
function handler(firstArg: string, secondArg: number): string 
function handler(firstArg: string, secondArg?: number): string | number {
  if (!!firstArg && !secondArg) {
   return   'implementation a'
  }
  return 'implementation b'
}

see about typescript function overloading
You also could define a more generic handler type:
type Handler = (firstArg: string, secondArg?: number) => string | number;

const testA: Handler = (a, b) => 'text'
const testB: Handler = (a) => 10


How does (a, b) => 10 match HandlerA? (Yes, I'm almost entirely ignorant about how functions work in Javascript. Can (a) => 10 accept additional arguments that it essentially ignores?)

@chepner i think you are referring to my second example where i mention You also could define a more generic handler type: if so then: when you use secondArg?: number you are saying that it can be omitted and by hovering you will see secondArg: number | undefined. The | means OR and the ? means "maybe" so yeah (a, b) => 10 matches because the result will be string | number and  (a) => 10 will also match because b may not exist, but if it does it will be a number.

Oh, I had it backwards. (a, b) => 10 is legal because testA("foo") is legal, with b being implicitly optional, but testB("foo", 5) is illegal because statically. we don't know that a second argument is allowed.

@chepner have you found your answer? Consider accepting this answer or suggesting changes.

Oh, sorry, this isn't my question; I'm just a static-typing enthusiast that doesn't use Typescript and was momentarily confused about your explanation.

XD sorry; i meant the OP @torsten.
